# Is nix on an Intel Mac too problematic?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, nix, macos

After too many errors I didn't know how to fix. I removed nix, even that was difficult. The nix blog show some progress in supporting M1 Macs but there are still problems. Has anyone succeeded with plutus projects with nix on an Intel Mac?

Comment: Please be more precise in what errors and problem you did encounter. This will make it easier to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. In fact I'm running the `plutus-playground-server` and `plutus-playground-client` on an `x86_64-darwin` machine with nix right now.

[image: plutus-playground on macOS]

Answer (score 0):

Intel Macs should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine - I got it running a day ago by following this guide which is for apple silicon (M1) macs : https://github.com/renzwo/cardano-plutus-apps-install-m1/blob/main/README.md

with 2 differences:

1. in step 3, when modifying nix.conf file, remove the "aarch64-darwin" string
2. later when you are starting plutus playground server and clients I did not need to prefix the commands with "GC_DONT_GC=1"

hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].